# Transitive models of ZFC and power set

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Let $M$ be a transitive model of ZFC.

From my understanding, if $x \in M$ then what $M$ believes to be its power set $\mathcal{P}(x)^M$ does not necessarily agree with the external power set $\mathcal{P}(x)$ (i.e. $\mathcal{P}(x)^M \neq \mathcal{P}(x)$), because $M$ might not contain all subsets of $x$.

Here is where my confusion begins: Let $\varphi(x,p) = \forall y (y \in p \leftrightarrow y \subseteq x)$ be the formula saying that $p$ is the power set of $x$. As $M$ is a model of ZFC we have $\varphi^M (x ,p)  \leftrightarrow \varphi(x, p)$ for any $x,p \in M$. 
But $\varphi^M (x , \mathcal{P}(x)^M)$ holds, which implies that $\mathcal{P}(x)^M = \mathcal{P}(x)$ and that $M$ is closed under subsets by transitivity. This doesn't agree with my understanding of transitive models mentioned above.

I should note, that I don't have much background in model theory and it is very likely that I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transitive models are closed under *elementhood*, not under *subsets*. In other words, $M$ is transitive if $x\in y\in M$ implies $x\in M$, and not as you suggest, $x\subseteq y\in M$ implies $x\in M$.

You are correct that if $M$ is transitive, and $x,y\in M$, then $M\models x\subseteq y$ if and only if $x\subseteq y$ (in $V$, that is). The only problem is that perhaps $x\notin M$.

But what you can say is that if $M$ is transitive, then $\mathcal P(x)^M=\mathcal P(x)\cap M$.

Comment: I am aware that transitive models are not necessarily closed under subsets, but I cannot see why my reasoning is faulty. Am I wrong in my assumption, that if $M$ is a model, then for any formula $\varphi$ with free variables among $x_1, \ldots ,x_n$ we have $\varphi^M(x_1,\ldots , x_n) \leftrightarrow \varphi(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$ for all $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in M$?

Comment: @AlexanderConstantin That is indeed wrong. And it's wrong exactly because transitive models need not be closed under subsets.

Comment: No, this is only true for $\Delta_1$ formulas, and the parameters need to be in $M$. So you can only conclude that sets that are in $M$ are in $M$.

Comment: @AlexanderConstantin Maybe you're mixing up transitive submodels and [*elementary* submodels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_equivalence#Elementary_substructures_and_elementary_extensions)? Indeed, what the above shows is that no countable elementary submodel of (a large enough part of) $V$ can be transitive.

Comment: That's exactly what happened and now I feel a bit embarrassed. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Asaf Karagila's answer covers the properties of transitive models, and where the argument in the OP breaks down. Let me add to that answer by saying a bit about the situation vis-a-vis a very different type of submodel: **elementary submodels**. Early on it's quite easy to mix these up, so this seems worthwhile to write out.

Ignore class/set issues for the moment (or replace $V$ with some big enough transitive set like $V_{somethingreallybig}$). By [downward Lowenheim-Skolem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem#Downward_part) we can find some countable $M\prec V$. Now we **do** have the bi-implication $\varphi^M\leftrightarrow\varphi$ in general, and the argument of the OP is now worrying again:

- Since $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ we have some $a\in M$ such that $M\models$ "$a$ is uncountable."
- By elementarity, $a$ is in fact uncountable.
- But $M$ is **countable**. What gives?

The resolution of the above issue is that $a\not\subseteq M$ - which is to say, $M$ must not be transitive. So the argument in the OP really reveals a tension between two conflicting "niceness" notions, namely *transitivity* and *elementarity*, and shows that while each individually is compatible with countability we can't have a countable submodel which is *both* transitive and elementary.

*(Note that the argument above is closely related to [Skolem's paradox](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-skolem/), which was the original appearance of the downward Lowenheim-Skolem theorem in the first place.)*

Both transitive and elementary countable submodels of $V$ play important roles in set theory; the above shows that they're really fundamentally different types of objects. That said:

- We can always turn an elementary submodel into a transitive submodel via the Mostowski collapse (note that this kills elementarity in general, of course).
- That said, transitive elementary submodels of $V$ do exist *(under mild hypotheses)* - they just have to be really really *really* **really** big. In particular, if $M$ is an elementary submodel of $V$ then any ordinal definable in $V$ has to be in $M$, and then by transitivity we get all the smaller ordinals too. And there could be really really big definable ordinals: maybe $\mathsf{GCH}$ fails somewhere but the first point of failure (which is definable) is really big, or your favorite [large cardinal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_cardinal) actually shows up (at which point its least instance, which has to be really big, is definable), or so forth. So transitive elementary submodels of $V$ only show up rarely.
- More technically, countable elementary submodels do have some weak transitivity properties - in particular, if $M\prec V$ then $\omega_1\cap M$ is closed downwards. This winds up being extremely useful down the road.